# how to run a c executable from MATLAB?

Tags: c, matlab, executable

I tried to run c executable from MATLAB file(CVAP valid_clusteringAlgs).But it doesnot work.Can someone help me or point to a good tutorial for achieving this

Comment: Explain in detail what you tried. Post explicit errors. THen we are more likely to be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out this link

[Click here](http://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/60270-how-run-c-program-in-matlab)

You have to create a MEX file for this. For more ideas you can refer the above link.